# Jenkins build console output error - couldn't find Maven version information

Tags: maven, selenium, jenkins, testng

I am using Jenkins for my Selenium testng Maven project. But when running the build, I am getting below console output. I have added correct MAVEN_HOME path but still getting this error -

```
Running as SYSTEM
Building in workspace /Users/priyanka.kadam/.jenkins/workspace/Ecommerce1
ERROR: Failed to parse POMs
java.io.IOException: hudson.maven.MavenEmbedderException: Couldn't find maven version information in '/Users/priyanka.kadam/Downloads/apache-maven-3.6.3'. Are you sure that this is a valid maven home?
    at hudson.maven.MavenVersionCallable.call(MavenVersionCallable.java:73)
    at hudson.maven.MavenVersionCallable.call(MavenVersionCallable.java:41)
    at hudson.FilePath.act(FilePath.java:1162)
    at hudson.maven.MavenModuleSetBuild$MavenModuleSetBuildExecution.doRun(MavenModuleSetBuild.java:641)
    at hudson.model.AbstractBuild$AbstractBuildExecution.run(AbstractBuild.java:504)
    at hudson.model.Run.execute(Run.java:1853)
    at hudson.maven.MavenModuleSetBuild.run(MavenModuleSetBuild.java:543)
    at hudson.model.ResourceController.execute(ResourceController.java:97)
    at hudson.model.Executor.run(Executor.java:427)
Caused by: hudson.maven.MavenEmbedderException: Couldn't find maven version information in '/Users/priyanka.kadam/Downloads/apache-maven-3.6.3'. Are you sure that this is a valid maven home?
    at hudson.maven.MavenEmbedderUtils.getMavenVersion(MavenEmbedderUtils.java:205)
    at hudson.maven.MavenEmbedderUtils.getMavenVersion(MavenEmbedderUtils.java:185)
    at hudson.maven.MavenVersionCallable.call(MavenVersionCallable.java:69)
    ... 8 more
Finished: FAILURE
```

Comment: maybe you're not referencing the right pom.xml

Comment: I am not seeing any error when I entered my project pom.xml path in Root POM field in Build section in Jenkins project configuration. Still I am seeing above error.

Comment: Jenkins wont able to pick up maven path. Make sure maven home setup on the system and in Jenkins configuration as well . Please refer to this tutorialspoint.com/jenkins/jenkins_maven_setup.htm

Answer (score 0):

Little late to the party, but I just had exactly this error message on MacOS, Jenkings and Maven installations via homebrew. My rookie mistake was that the maven home directory (M2_HOME) is maven's libexec directory, probably something like

```
/usr/local/Cellar/maven/3.x.y/libexec
```